# Enum like calculated constants

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

Actually this "problem" feels extremely simple. While doing some calculated icon offsets, I came up with the following approach:

```
namespace Icons {

  struct IconSet {
    constexpr IconSet(size_t base_offset) noexcept
      : base_offset_(base_offset), icon(base_offset * 3), iconSmall(icon + 1), iconBig(icon + 2) {
    }
    size_t icon;
    size_t iconSmall;
    size_t iconBig;

    size_t base_offset_;

    constexpr size_t next() const {
      return base_offset_ + 1;
    }
  };


  static constexpr IconSet flower = IconSet(0);
  static constexpr IconSet tree = IconSet(flower.next());
  static constexpr IconSet forest = IconSet(tree.next());
  static constexpr IconSet mountain = IconSet(forest.next());

 }
```

Now one may write `Icons::tree.iconBig` for example to get that icon's calculated offset. Basically the designer can change the icons - sometimes adding/removing as well - but always has to provide the entire set (normal, small and big) by convention.

As you see, the issue with this approach is that I had to do that `next()` function and use it repeatedly - a normal enum wouldn't have this downside.

I know of BOOST_PP and other macro tricks, but I was hoping for something without macro's - since I have a feeling it is not needed and I then sort of would prefer what I already have with the plain `next()` function.
Another solution would of course just be a normal enum and a calculation function, but that is defeating the purpose of laying it out precalculated.

Hence, I am looking for a simple and portable solution that will give that enum-like functionality. It doesn't have to be compile time or `constexpr` if for example just inline will make it easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an approach you can use, based on a fold expression over a compile time integer sequence to instantiate the icons by index. The structured binding gets you individually named non-static, non-constexpr variables.

The anonymous namespace inside `Icons` makes those definitions visible in this translation unit only, which you may or may not want.

[Compiler explorer link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/kVeWdS) so you can explore the code options yourself.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>
#include <utility>

namespace Icons {

struct IconSet {
    constexpr IconSet(size_t base_offset) noexcept 
      : base_offset_(base_offset), icon(base_offset * 3), iconSmall(icon + 1), iconBig(icon + 2) {
    }
    size_t icon;
    size_t iconSmall;
    size_t iconBig;

    size_t base_offset_;
};

template <std::size_t... Ints>
constexpr auto make_icons_helper(std::index_sequence<Ints...>) -> std::array<IconSet, sizeof...(Ints)> 
{
    return {IconSet(Ints)...};
}

template <size_t N>
constexpr auto make_icons()
{
    return make_icons_helper(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

namespace {
    auto [flower, tree, forest, mountain] = make_icons<4>();
}

}

int main()
{
    return Icons::forest.iconSmall;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple, non-constexpr solution using a static counter and relying on the fact that static initialization is performed top-to-bottom within a single TU:

```
namespace Icons {
  namespace detail_iconSet {
    static std::size_t current_base_offset = 0;
  }

  struct IconSet {
    IconSet() noexcept 
      : base_offset_(detail_iconSet::current_base_offset++)
      , icon(base_offset_ * 3)
      , iconSmall(icon + 1)
      , iconBig(icon + 2) { }

    std::size_t base_offset_;

    std::size_t icon;
    std::size_t iconSmall;
    std::size_t iconBig;
  };


  static IconSet flower;
  static IconSet tree;
  static IconSet forest;
  static IconSet mountain;
}
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1dd80c9606a6f595)

The catch is that this will behave weirdly if you have several headers containing `IconSet` definitions (i.e. their numbering will change depending on the order of inclusion), but then I don't think there's a way to avoid that.

Comment: This will need a big fat comment to point out that it's relying on static initialization order.

Comment: @MaxLanghof should I put the very first sentence in title font? :p

Comment: I didn't mean "your answer fails to mention the fact" but "this is _really_ fragile code and should be _very clearly_ marked as such before going anywhere close to production". ;)